# Oracle Apex 19.2: Cannot resolve the "schema is reserved or restricted" issue

Tags: oracle, schema, oracle-apex, oracle19c

I attempted to create a workspace in APEX using an existing schema called *PEOPLE* and it gave the error message **"The schema is reserved or restricted"**. I tried with other existing schemas that I created and they all worked fine.

Technical/Environment details follow:

Database: Oracle 19c EE installed on local machine.
Apex: 19.2 installed as Embedded Gateway on local machine.

Created pluggable database called *PDB1*.
Created tablespace *PEOPLE_TAB* using OMF (Oracle Managed Files) syntax.
Created local user *PEOPLE* in *PDB1*.

Gave *PEOPLE* the following roles and privs (I'm aware some are doubled up like RESOURCE role and CREATE SESSION priv):

```
RESOURCE
UNLIMITED TABLESPACE
SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE
CREATE SESSION
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TYPE
CREATE CLUSTER
CREATE TRIGGER
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE VIEW
CREATE DIMENSION
CREATE JOB
CREATE SYNONYM 
CREATE DIMENSION
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
```

I created another user *TEST1* in the same tablespace *PEOPLE_TAB*, with the same privs as *PEOPLE* and re-created the objects and data. I could successfully create a workspace using this new schema!

Trawled the web, but most articles and posts refer to older versions of APEX, but I still tried the following.

I followed the advice given in the Oracle docs, [Application Express Release 19.2 Adminstration Guide section 2.13](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeadm/managing-schemas.html#GUID-21F40BBE-BD84-4435-A326-B267D9A21029)

The APEX engine schema for APEX 19.2 is *APEX_190200*. So I unlocked *APEX_190200* and logged in (after changing password) to run the checks.

```
-- Checked if PEOPLE was a restricted schema
SELECT schema FROM APEX_190200.wwv_flow_restricted_schemas order by schema;
```

*PEOPLE* is not listed and I assume is not restricted. So I tried to unrestrict *PEOPLE* anyway as detailed in the docs.

```
-- ran from APEX_190200
EXEC APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.UNRESTRICT_SCHEMA(p_schema => 'PEOPLE');
COMMIT;
```

Successfully ran but did not resolve the issue.

Looking on the web most of the info was out of date but tried anyway.

```
-- ran from APEX_190200
EXEC APEX_SITE_ADMIN_PRIVS.UNRESTRICT_SCHEMA(p_schema => 'PEOPLE');
COMMIT;
```

The above did not run and complained the package didn't exist. I verified that when looking for *APEX_SITE_ADMIN_PRIVS* in user_objects - it was not there.

Some years ago there was a bug with the function wwv_flow_provision.IS_RESERVED, but I checked this and it ran ok returning FALSE for *PEOPLE* and TRUE for reserved words like VARCHAR.

It's really thrown me when I can create an identical user (different name) with identical privs, objects and data was created on the same tablespace and it worked fine with an APEX workspace.

Does anyone have any experience of resolving this issue or point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you afford dropping PEOPLE user and creating it back, with all privileges it has now, tables ... everything (just like you did with that "identical" user)?

Comment: @Littlefoot I can, but if this was to happen in a production environment where dropping and re-creating may not be an option, I really wanted to find a solution for this. All it requires is some way to unrestrict the PEOPLE schema, but I have exhausted the avenues I'm aware of.

Comment: Right; that's why I asked that question. If nothing else works, maybe DROP + CREATE will do the job.

Comment: I'm clearly missing a trick here as there must be a way of unrestricting a schema in this situation.

Comment: If you ever find the reason/answer/solution, please, post it here. I'm really curious.

Comment: @Littlefoot Definitely, it's really doing my head in now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving the error because `PEOPLE` is specified as a restricted schema with an APEX package.

In the installation scripts for APEX 19.2, the file named **f4050.sql** has a page validation on page 79 (the page that is raising the error) that looks like this:

```
...
...
...
wwv_flow_api.create_page_validation(
 p_id=>wwv_flow_api.id(114752711027135415)
,p_validation_name=>'schema not reserved/restricted'
,p_validation_sequence=>80
,p_validation=>wwv_flow_string.join(wwv_flow_t_varchar2(
'wwv_flow_provision.schema_name_valid(',
'    p_schema            => :F4050_P79_SCHEMA,',
'    p_workspace_name    => :F4050_P27_COMPANY);'))
,p_validation_type=>'PLSQL_EXPRESSION'
,p_error_message=>'Schema is reserved or restricted'
,p_when_button_pressed=>wwv_flow_api.id(12559200978895311)
,p_error_display_location=>'INLINE_WITH_FIELD_AND_NOTIFICATION'
);
...
...
...
```

Then using a procedure block like this, you can determine if the schema name is valid or not:

```sql
BEGIN
    IF apex_190200.wwv_flow_provision.schema_name_valid (p_schema           => 'PEOPLE',
                                                         p_workspace_name   => 'PEOPLE')
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Valid');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Invalid');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Then by unwrapping the code in those packages (tools can be easily found online).  Within that code, there is a call to another function named `WWV_FLOW_PROVISIONING.RESERVED_SCHEMA (P_SCHEMA => P_SCHEMA)`. Within that function, there is code that looks like this:

```sql
    IF C_SCHEMA IN (
        'HTMLDB_PUBLIC_USER',
        'APEX_PUBLIC_USER',
        'PUBLIC_USER',
        'FLOWS_FILES',
        'SCHEDULER',
        'PEOPLE') THEN
        
        RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;
```

So without modifying the package `WWV_FLOW_PROVISIONING` (which I would highly recommend **AGAINST**), you will not be able to create an APEX workspace with the schema name **PEOPLE**. This will need to be fixed by Oracle either through a patch to the package or in a newer version of APEX.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has explained the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fascinating issue.  The restricted schema is hard-coded in APEX provisioning code.  It's very much a legacy issue.

We can attempt to fix this in the next release of APEX, but that won't help you now.  If you file a Service Request for Oracle Support, I'll make sure you get a fix for this issue (assuming you're using a supported version of APEX).